# Couchbase Converter Spring Data confusing Integer with Long

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase

I added a couchbase converter for `Instant` <=> `Long` but I am getting an error when reading the value.

`org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [java.time.Instant]`

My converters look like this

```
  @WritingConverter
  public enum InstantToLongConverter implements Converter<Instant, Long> {
    INSTANCE;

    public Long convert(Instant source) {
      return source == null ? null : source.getEpochSecond();
    }
  }

  @ReadingConverter
  public enum LongToInstantConverter implements Converter<Long, Instant> {
    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public Instant convert(Long source) {
      return source == null ? null : Instant.ofEpochSecond(source);
    }
  }
```

Should i just use Integer?
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long, their common ancestor is java.lang.Number. Meaning, your converter Long <=> Instant cannot be used by Spring data to convert an Integer.

Possible solutions:

- Modify your converter to convert Number <=> Instant
- Create another converter Integer <=> Instant

Answer (score -1):

The following is about method overloading:

Integer is never bound to Long because Integer and Long are different object types and there is no IS-A relation between them. This is true for any two wrapper classes.

It could, however, be bound to Object because Integer IS-A Object.